# How do I find the missing equation?

Tags: circuit-analysis, basic

This is my first post here, hope you all doing well. I'm a CS student, having my first class on circuits. I've been given this problem (see picture) where I'm asked to find V2. I'm missing one equation, which I can't seem to find? In the first equation, with the currents, I'm assuming that all the currents are flowing away from V2.

I know that this may be very basic, but it's all very new to me.

[image]

Comment: You are missing KCL for the ground node, relating current through the 4 ohm and 8 ohm resistors and the current source.

Comment: So, 5 - v3/8 - V1/4 = 0. Am I right?

Comment: It could look like this \$ \frac{V_1}{4\Omega}+ \frac{V_1 - V_2}{2\Omega}+\frac{V_3}{8\Omega}+\frac{V_3 - V_2}{2\Omega}=0\$

Comment: I think you're right, Daniel. But Elliot's answer sounds right too though. I assume one of them will be redundant.

Comment: @DanielOscar Thanks for the accept, but it's better to wait a day to give people time to answer. Someone else might write an answer you like more, and accepting early discourages future answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to account for the current through the 4\$\Omega\$ and 8\$\Omega\$ resistors. You can either:

1. Do as Justin suggests and write a KCL equation for the ground node. This is basically the same as picking a different reference node, so it won't work in circuits with multiple voltage sources.
2. Define an unknown current \$I_S\$ through the voltage source, then add KCL equations for nodes \$V_1\$ and \$V_3\$, giving four equations in total.
3. Use the supernode method as Elliot suggests, which is a shortcut for #2.

Answer (score 0):

There are four nodes in the circuit, and one has been designated as the reference node (ground). So, you need to write KCL equations at each of the remaining three nodes.

Since you have a voltage source in the circuit you can't write KCL equations at the two nodes connected to the voltage source. Instead you must treat the voltage source as a **supernode** and write a single equation for the sum of currents into the two nodes of the supernode. It's this equation that you lack.

You then need an equation for the voltage between those two nodes, which you already have.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem is easiest to do by superposition.

Remove the current source. Now solve for currents and voltages due to the voltage source alone.

Put the current source back and replace the voltage source with a piece of wire. Now solve for currents and voltages due to the current source alone.

Now add the two solutions together, all nodal voltages add, all branch currents add.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFWmd2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
0=\text{I}_\text{y}+\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
0=\text{I}_\text{x}+\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{x}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{y}=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_voltage_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{V}_\text{y}=\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$